# Групповое сообщение в Telebot(python)

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Нужно одним сообщением отправить фото, текст и локацию. Подскажите пожалуйста, как 
это можно сделать с помощью telebot python?

Comment: вы можете привести пример такого сообщения? может скриншот?

Answer (score 1):

Сгруппировать фото и текст(описание под текстом) еще можно, но локацию нельзя. Функция для отправки фотографий send_photo имеет атрибут caption который принимает на вход строку.

```
bot.send_photo(something, caption='Ваше описание')
```

Думаю можно просто в описании указать что следом за сообщением была выслана локация.